# DistributedCache - Loading file in memory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, distributed-cache

Is there any method in hadoop that i can override that is called before the job starts?
I would like to load a file from distributed cache. I cannot put it on setup method of the mapper class because i will have many mappers. I will use MultipleInputs.

I will filter my inputs based on a file in the distributed cache.

Thanks!

Comment: I could use a singleton to solve this problem too.

Comment: I cannot fully understand your question, I would appreciate if you could extend it or at least give more details.